# How can I create a path for the robot to go along the wall during autonomous navigation?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, path-planning

I am developing a robot using ROS (Robot Operating System). The goal is to enable the robot to navigate a closed environment, approaching all walls to scan the surroundings. I have a map of the environment that indicates the locations of the walls. I plan to use an algorithm similar to the A* algorithm, but with a modification: the robot should move at a distance of approximately 80-100 cm from the walls. This will allow the robot to scan the environment more effectively and detect walls from a closer distance.

The robot will start from the charging station, move according to the specified algorithm, approach the walls to scan the environment, and after completing the exploration of the entire map, return to the charging station. This process will enable the robot to continuously explore the environment and automatically return to the station for recharging when needed. Do you have any suggestions for me to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Okay i edited my question.